# Angular swiper slides don't snap

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I am trying to implement the [Swiper Angular library](https://swiperjs.com/angular/) into my Angular 10/Ionic 5 project. The problem I'm having is that the slides don't snap and it seems like it's just one big page I can drag through.

This is the Getting Started example I have tried, it shows the pages right, I believe, but the swiping part seems a bit off, with no snapping and it doesn't keep sliding if you let go, like shown [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swiper-angular-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

```
<swiper class ="slide-pic-preview" [slidesPerView]="3" [spaceBetween]="50"
        (swiper)="onSwiper($event)" (slideChange)="onSlideChange()"
        [navigation]="true" [pagination]="{ clickable: true }">

  <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 1</ng-template>
  <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 2</ng-template>
  <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 3</ng-template>
  <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 4</ng-template>
  <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 5</ng-template>
  <ng-template swiperSlide>Slide 6</ng-template>
</swiper>
```

I have also installed all the components needed for the navigating part in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
SwiperCore.use([Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y]); }
```

The naviagtion buttons also don't do anything than triggering the onSlideChange Event, so does normal swiping, but not with each page instead its like every 20px I drag it around the event gets fired.

And the style is imported in the modules scss file.

Update: I just found out that resizing the browser window fixes this problem, now I just need to find out how to intially make it work

Comment: "slides don't snap" what is that meaning?

Comment: If you click on the second link you can see that in the example it 'snaps' to each page after dragging it and doesn't just stay where it was or where you dragged it

Comment: Try setting a fixed width and height on the element (e.g. 100%).

Comment: Already tried that, I found a fix tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is @R4yYs answer but with a modification to stop the swiper index resetting.  Otherwise this causes a reset of the slide index in Ionic/ angular back to 0 if you go to another page/tab.

```
 @ViewChild('swiper') swiper: Swiper;
  hasRunContentCheck = false;

  ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    if (this.swiper && !this.hasRunContentCheck) {
      this.hasRunContentCheck = true;
      this.swiper.updateSwiper({});
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

So I found the solution on my own:

```
@ViewChild('swiper') swiper: Swiper;  

  ngAfterContentChecked(): void
  {
    if(this.swiper){
      // @ts-ignore
      //This really works, trust me
      this.swiper.updateSwiper({});
    }
  }
```

Updating the swiper once it comes into the view of the user fixes this issue.

Comment: This causes a reset of the slide index in Ionic/ angular back to 0 if you go to another page/tab.  Any fix for this?