# ngx-Swiper not snapping properly

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I'm tring to integrate [ngx-swiper-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper) in an angular/ionic project. However, the 'slides' don't seem to snap properly. One slide is supposed to be shown at the same time, but some kind of infinite scroll appears, with slides starting off-screen and ending offscreen and no slide snapping to the viewport.

The code used is the following;

```
<swiper class="swiper-container" fxFlex="auto" [config]="config" (indexChange)="onIndexChange($event)">
  <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 1
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 2
  </div>
</swiper>
```

With the following in the component;

```
public config: SwiperConfigInterface = {
      direction: 'horizontal',
      loop: true,
      slidesPerView: 1,
      keyboard: true,
      mousewheel: true,
      scrollbar: false,
      navigation: true,
      pagination: true
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things, instead of using [ngx-swiper-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-swiper-wrapper) you could use the official npm package of swiper, which already has support for Angular [Swiper Angular](https://swiperjs.com/angular). No need to use the wrapper anymore, and also its last update was 1 year+

Either way, you probably can fix that by doing something this:

```js
  ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    if (this.swiper) {
      this.swiper.update();
    }
  }

  onSwiper(swiperRef: any) {
    this.swiper = swiperRef;
  }
```

```html
<swiper class="swiper-container" fxFlex="auto" [config]="config" (swiper)="onSwiper($event)" (indexChange)="onIndexChange($event)">
  <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 1
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
      Slide 2
  </div>
</swiper>
```

Taken this based on the answers here by MadMac & R4yY
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68779564/2276364